# Application and TCP buffers with OpenSSL

Tags: sockets, ssl, tcp, network-programming, openssl

I am writing a Client Server program. In order to achieve the Network Throughput I was playing around with the Application buffer size and TCP Buffer size (SO_SNDBUF/SO_RCVBUF) to find the best values for a specific client-server pair. I am transferring a file of size 748MB from Client to Server which are in LAN.

I had tested this with Basic TCP and OpenSSL enabled Client Server program and have measured the time it takes to transfer the file.
1)    In Basic TCP Client Server program I could see the gain at the different combinations of those 2 buffer values.
2)    In OpenSSL enabled Client Server I couldn’t see such gain and the values are too high as compared to Basic TCP Client Server.

Here are few results:

**TCP Client**

```
[root@vl-blg-dv10 dipak]# zsh  
[root@vl-blg-dv10]~/dipak# ./tcp-client_1  
usage: ./tcp-client_1 [IPAddress] [port] [filename] [bufferSize] [tcpbufsize]  
[root@vl-blg-dv10]~/dipak# time ./tcp-client_1 10.129.85.242 32000 /tmp/748M 16384 65536 >/dev/null  
./tcp-client_1 10.129.85.242 32000 /tmp/748M 16384 65536 > /dev/null  0.06s user 1.47s system 4% cpu 33.930 total  
[root@vl-blg-dv10]~/dipak# time ./tcp-client_1 10.129.85.242 32000 /tmp/748M 65536 131072 >/dev/null  
./tcp-client_1 10.129.85.242 32000 /tmp/748M 65536 131072 > /dev/null  0.02s user 1.20s system 14% cpu 8.503 total  
[root@vl-blg-dv10]~/dipak# time ./tcp-client_1 10.129.85.242 32000 /tmp/748M 131072 524288 >/dev/null  
./tcp-client_1 10.129.85.242 32000 /tmp/748M 131072 524288 > /dev/null  0.01s user 1.06s system 20% cpu 5.154 total  
[root@vl-blg-dv10]~/dipak#
```

**OpenSSL Enabled Client**

```
[root@vl-blg-dv10]~/dipak# ./SSL_Client_3  
usage: ./SSL_Client_3 [hostname] [portnum] [FileName] [AppBufferSize] [TCPBufferSize]  
[root@vl-blg-dv10]~/dipak# time ./SSL_Client_3 10.129.85.242 32000 /tmp/748M 16384 65536 > /dev/null  
./SSL_Client_3 10.129.85.242 32000 /tmp/748M 16384 65536 > /dev/null  68.20s user 3.68s system 86% cpu 1:23.19 total  
[root@vl-blg-dv10]~/dipak# time ./SSL_Client_3 10.129.85.242 32000 /tmp/748M 65536 131072 > /dev/null  
./SSL_Client_3 10.129.85.242 32000 /tmp/748M 65536 131072 > /dev/null  59.22s user 2.20s system 86% cpu 1:11.06 total  
[root@vl-blg-dv10]~/dipak# time ./SSL_Client_3 10.129.85.242 32000 /tmp/748M 131072 524288 > /dev/null  
./SSL_Client_3 10.129.85.242 32000 /tmp/748M 131072 524288 > /dev/null  62.15s user 2.45s system 88% cpu 1:12.92 total  
[root@vl-blg-dv10]~/dipak#
```

**SCP**
With SCP it is taking around 22 Seconds.

```
[root@vl-blg-dv10]~/dipak# time scp /tmp/748M root@10.129.85.242:/tmp/  
root@10.129.85.242's password:  
748M                                          100%  748MB  34.0MB/s   00:22  
scp /tmp/748M root@10.129.85.242:/tmp/  13.66s user 6.42s system 69% cpu 28.784 total  
[root@vl-blg-dv10]~/dipak#
```

I noticed that in case of OpenSSL Enabled Client the time spend in the “User Space” is high (around 60 seconds). So I guess this is mostly because of the encryption activity.
Please find the source code below for reference. Has anyone faced/noticed such issue? Is there anything wrong I am doing with my OpenSSL code or anything needs to be tweaked to achieve the performance?

Any pointers, suggestions are always welcome....

Thanks,
Dipak

//SSL-Client.c

```
//################SSL-Client.c #######################
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>

#define FAIL    -1

void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{
 /* set the local certificate from CertFile */
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* verify private key */
    if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
        abort();
    }
}

int OpenConnection(const char *hostname, int port, int tbuf_size)
{   int sd, val;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    if ((host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL)
    {
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);

    val = tbuf_size;
    printf ("Using TCP buffer size (SO_SNDBUF/SO_RCVBUF) = <%d>\n", val);
    setsockopt (sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&val, sizeof (val));
    setsockopt (sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char *)&val, sizeof (val));

    val = 1;
    setsockopt (sd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&val, sizeof(val));
    val = IPTOS_THROUGHPUT | IPTOS_LOWDELAY;
    setsockopt (sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TOS, (char *)&val, sizeof(val));

    if (connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0)
    {
        close(sd);
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{   SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();    /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();        /* Bring in and register error messages */
    method = SSLv2_client_method();  /* Create new client-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);       /* Create new context */
    if (ctx == NULL)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    LoadCertificates(ctx, "client_cert.pem", "client_key.pem"); /* load certs */
    return ctx;
}

int main(int count, char *argv[])
{  
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    SSL *ssl;
    char *hostname, *portnum;
    char *recvBuff1;
    int fd=0;
    int rlen;
    long sz=0;
    struct stat st;
    int read_cnt;
    int data_cnt;
    int tobe_read_cnt;
    int ok;
    int app_buf_size = 0;
    int tcp_buf_size = 0;

    if (count != 6)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <hostname> <portnum> <FileName> <AppBufferSize> <TCPBufferSize>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    hostname=argv[1];
    portnum=argv[2];
    app_buf_size = atoi (argv[4]);
    tcp_buf_size = atoi (argv[5]);

    if (stat(argv[3], &st) < 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "stat() failed. Error = %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    printf ("Using Application buffer size = <%d>\n", app_buf_size);
    recvBuff1 = malloc (app_buf_size);
    data_cnt = st.st_size;
    ctx = InitCTX();
    server = OpenConnection(hostname, atoi(portnum), tcp_buf_size);
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */
    //SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");

    if (SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL)   /* perform the connection */
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        close(server);         /* close socket */
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        /* release context */
        return -1;
    }
    printf ("Connected to %s:%s\n", hostname, portnum);
    printf ("SSL_get_cipher_name returned <%s>\n", SSL_get_cipher_name(ssl));
    fd = open (argv[3], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to open the file <%s>\n", argv[3]);
        return 0;
    }
    read_cnt = 0;
    ok = 1;
    tobe_read_cnt = app_buf_size;

    //Send the Application buffer size to be used for read
    SSL_write(ssl, &app_buf_size, sizeof(app_buf_size));   /* encrypt & send message */

    while (1)
    {
        if (data_cnt < read_cnt + tobe_read_cnt)
            tobe_read_cnt = data_cnt - read_cnt;
        if((rlen = read(fd, recvBuff1, tobe_read_cnt)) > 0)
        {
           read_cnt += rlen;
        }
        else
           break;

        sz = SSL_write (ssl, recvBuff1,rlen );   /* encrypt & send message */
        if (sz != rlen)
        {
           fprintf (stderr, "Write data length <%ld> doesn't match input data length <%d>\n", sz, rlen);
        }
        if (data_cnt == read_cnt)
        {
           printf ("Sucessfully sent data of length %d\n", read_cnt);
           ok = 0;
           break;
        }
    }
    SSL_free(ssl);        /* release connection state */
    close(server);         /* close socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        /* release context */
    return 0;
}
```

//SSL-Server.c

```
//########################SSL-Server.c#########################
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define FAIL    -1

int non_ssl;

int OpenListener(int port, int tbuf_size)
{   int sd, val;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    val = tbuf_size;
    printf ("Using TCP buffer size (SO_SNDBUF/SO_RCVBUF) = <%d>\n", val);
    setsockopt (sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&val, sizeof (val));
    setsockopt (sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char *)&val, sizeof (val));

    val = 1;
    setsockopt (sd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&val, sizeof(val));
    val = IPTOS_THROUGHPUT | IPTOS_LOWDELAY;
    setsockopt (sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TOS, (char *)&val, sizeof(val));

    if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0)
    {
        perror("can't bind port");
        abort();
    }
    if (listen(sd, 64) != 0)
    {
        perror("Can't configure listening port");
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void)
{   SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* load all error messages */
    method = SSLv2_server_method();  /* create new server-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* create new context from method */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{
    /* set the local certificate from CertFile */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

    /* verify private key */
    if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
        abort();
    }

}


void Servlet(SSL* ssl) /* Serve the connection request*/
{   char *buf;
    int sd, bytes;
    int fd=0;
    int len;
    char filename [32];
    int app_buf_size = 0;

    if (SSL_accept(ssl) == FAIL)     /* do SSL-protocol accept */
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);       /* get socket connection */
        SSL_free(ssl);         /* release SSL state */
        close(sd);          /* close connection */
        return;
    }

    sprintf (filename, "/tmp/test1");

    fd = open (filename, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666);

    if (fd < 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to open the file %s, error = %s", filename, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    //Get Application buffer size to be used.
    SSL_read(ssl, &app_buf_size, sizeof(app_buf_size));
    printf ("Using Application buffer size as <%d>\n", app_buf_size);
    buf = malloc (app_buf_size);

    while(1)
    {
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, app_buf_size); /* get request */
        //bytes = read(non_ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get request */
        if (bytes <= 0)
        {
            ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
            break;
        }

        len=write(fd,buf,bytes);

    }

    sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);       /* get socket connection */
    SSL_free(ssl);         /* release SSL state */
    close(sd);          /* close connection */
    close(fd);
    free(buf);
    unlink(filename);
}

int main(int count, char *argv[])
{   SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    int portnum;
    int pid;
    int tcp_buf_size = 0;

    if (count != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <portnum> <tcpbufsize>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    SSL_library_init();

    portnum = atoi (argv[1]);
    tcp_buf_size = atoi (argv[2]);
    server = OpenListener(portnum, tcp_buf_size);    /* create server socket */

    ctx = InitServerCTX();        /* initialize SSL */
    LoadCertificates(ctx, "server_cert.pem", "server_key.pem"); /* load certs */

    while (1)
    {   struct sockaddr_in addr;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
        SSL *ssl;

        int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);  /* accept connection as usual */
        if (client < 0)
           break;

        printf("Accepted Connection: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            ssl = SSL_new(ctx);              /* get new SSL state with context */
            SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);      /* set connection socket to SSL state */
            OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
            non_ssl=client;
            Servlet(ssl);         /* service connection */
            printf("Done.\n\n");
            _exit (0);
        }
        else
        {
            //Parent wait for next client
            continue;
        }
    }

    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);         /* release context */
    close(server);          /* close server socket */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Dipak. You should ask narrow, directed questions, and you should provide a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't think you've done either here. For example, dumping your entire client and server code base does not seem like its providing the minimum example to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: For folks who are looking to optimize file transfer, they often avoid TLS altogether. You first option is to use DTLS to avoid the slow start and sliding windows. But you will need to implement book keeping and ask for resends of lost datagrams. Also see [openssl optimize file transfer](https://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+optimize+file+transer) returned by Google. There's entire bodies of knowledge around it. There are also products designed around solving this problem, like [Aspera](http://asperasoft.com/).

Comment: Sorry about the continued comment.... You can also optimize the Time To First Byte, but that's a small portion of the problem in general. For that, see something like [Optimizing NGINX TLS Time To First Byte (TTTFB)](https://www.igvita.com/2013/12/16/optimizing-nginx-tls-time-to-first-byte/).